# PHP how to search file for specific variable and display all lines connected to it - see details

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What I need to do is find specific unique number in text, which may occur multiple times in a document.  I need to display all lines that are connected to it, and all occurrences. If you check file sample you can see that common separator is ===. So I was thinking to use some regular expression that will check for searched number and display all lines between two ===.  And with help of preg_match run the search through file.
At the moment i dont know how to write regular expression, can you help me with it?

File simple:

```
=======================================================
= Elapsed: yxz ms
= In msg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><BLRequest xmlns="http://www.wwww.ww/wwww/">  *** <find_me>12345678901</find_me> *** </BLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
= Out msg: <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns:envelope="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" envelope:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> *** </Body></Envelope>
=======================================================
=======================================================
= Elapsed: yxz ms
= In msg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><BLRequest xmlns="http://www.wwww.ww/wwww/">  *** <find_me>6545678901</find_me> *** </BLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
= Out msg: <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns:envelope="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" envelope:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> *** </Body></Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http " > *** </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
=======================================================
=======================================================
= Elapsed: yxz ms
= In msg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><BLRequest xmlns="http://www.wwww.ww/wwww/">  *** <find_me>12345678901</find_me> *** </BLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
= Out msg: <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns:envelope="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" envelope:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> *** </Body></Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http " > *** </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
=======================================================
```

Also i wrote a code where should be this regular expression be inserted, is it ok or there is a better way to do this ?

```
<?php

$file ='myFile.log';
$search = '12345678901'; //find_me
$pattern = '/(?<========================================================).*?(?========================================================)/s';


$file = fopen($file, "r") or die("Cannot open file!\n"); 
while ($line = fgets($file, 1024)) { 
    if (preg_match($pattern, $line)) { 
        echo "Results:</br> " . $line; 
    } else { 
        echo "No match: " . $line; 
    } 
} 
fclose($file); 

?>
```

Note that:
file could be up to 200Mb. 
Current RE is not correct it is one of my attempts 
Also, is it possible to display results as xml ? since there are xml lines in file ?

Comment: Do `strpos($line,$search)!==false` instead of `preg_match($pattern, $line)` and `possible to display results as xml` sure, but that is more work :-)

Comment: I had that attempt but it displays only line where result is found. `while( !feof( $fp)) {
   $line = fgets( $fp);
   if( !( strpos( $line, $needle) === false)) {
      
   echo 'Found ' . $needle . ' in line #' . $line_number . 
   echo '</br>That line contains: ' . nl2br($line);
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution that deals with large files:

```
$filename = 'file.txt';
$search   = '12345678901'; //find_me
$pattern  = "/(?<=====)(?:(?!====).)+($search)(?:(?!====).)+(?=====)/s";

$handle  = fopen($filename , "r") or die("Cannot open $filename!\n"); 
$out = array();
$start = 0;
$found = 0;
while($line = fgets($handle)) {
    if (preg_match('/^==========/', $line)) {
        if ($start) {
            if ($found) {
                foreach($out as $ll) echo $ll,"\n";
            }
            $found = 0;
            $start = 0;
            $out = [];
        } else {
            $start = 1;
            $out[] = $line;
        }
    } else {
        if ($start) {
            $out[] = $line;
            if (preg_match("/$search/", $line)) $found = 1;
        }
    }

}
fclose($handle);
```

**Output:**

```
=======================================================

= Elapsed: yxz ms

= In msg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><BLRequest xmlns="http://www.wwww.ww/wwww/">  *** <find_me>12345678901</find_me> *** </BLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

= Out msg: <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns:envelope="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" envelope:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> *** </Body></Envelope>

=======================================================

= Elapsed: yxz ms

= In msg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><BLRequest xmlns="http://www.wwww.ww/wwww/">  *** <find_me>12345678901</find_me> *** </BLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

= Out msg: <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns:envelope="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" envelope:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> *** </Body></Envelope>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http " > *** </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: thanks for quick replay. I am not receiving the same output. `======================================================= = Elapsed: 1 ms = In msg: *** 12345678901 *** = Out msg: *** ======================================================= = Elapsed: 3 ms = In msg: *** 12345678901 *** = Out msg: *** *** ` But if i change /n to </br> output is formatted as yours and that is fine for me. 
Although, as you can see, not all data is displayed only the searched number. If i run this on original file i don't receive any output and no error is shown

Comment: @strumpf: `fgets` read the file line by line (ie. between two linebreak), you can't use it to read line that are separated by `<br>`. You have to convert `<br>` into `\n` in the file before processing it.

Comment: it works, thanks. But I am still confused about `</br>` and `\n` because if i use `\n` everything is in one line and it breaks in the end of the screen and continue to another line. if i change it to `foreach($out as $ll) echo $ll,"</br>";` output is like yours with one exception xml code is not displayed only data (which is ok for me too)

Comment: @strumpf: It depends if you visualize output in a console (which needs `\n`) or in a navigator (which needs `<br>`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the whole file then test against the pattern. The pattern must contain the search:

```
$filename = 'file.txt';
$search   = '12345678901'; //find_me
$pattern  = "/(?<=====)(?:(?!====).)+($search)(?:(?!====).)+(?=====)/s";

$handle  = fopen($filename , "r") or die("Cannot open $filename!\n"); 
$content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches)) { 
    print_r($matches);
} else { 
    echo "No match: \n"; 
} 
fclose($handle);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ===
= Elapsed: yxz ms
= In msg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><BLRequest xmlns="http://www.wwww.ww/wwww/">  *** <find_me>12345678901</find_me> *** </BLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
= Out msg: <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns:envelope="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" envelope:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> *** </Body></Envelope>

            [1] => ===
= Elapsed: yxz ms
= In msg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><BLRequest xmlns="http://www.wwww.ww/wwww/">  *** <find_me>12345678901</find_me> *** </BLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
= Out msg: <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns:envelope="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" envelope:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> *** </Body></Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http " > *** </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12345678901
            [1] => 12345678901
        )

)
```

Comment: this is very helpful, but when i run this on original file i get fatal error - memory size exhausted. Is there better way to do this and less memory consuming ? Also what is the best way to print this without Array. Trying to make this human readable as much as possible.

Comment: @strumpf:Sorry,It will not work with big files, because all the file is in memory. I'll come bask with another answer.